# Fitting negative binomial in python

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, distribution, statsmodels

In scipy there is no support for fitting a negative binomial distribution using data
(maybe due to the fact that the negative binomial in scipy is only discrete).

For a normal distribution I would just do:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
param = norm.fit(samp)
```

Is there something similar 'ready to use' function in any other library?

Comment: Have you found the solution to this question?

Comment: Please see the answer from @Eran.
statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.NegativeBinomial

Answer (score 8):

Statsmodels has discrete.discrete_model.NegativeBinomial.fit(), see here:
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.NegativeBinomial.fit.html#statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.NegativeBinomial.fit

Answer (score 7):

Not only because it is discrete, also because maximum likelihood fit to negative binomial can be quite involving, especially with an additional location parameter. That would be the reason why `.fit()` method is not provided for it (and other discrete distributions in `Scipy`), here is an example:

```
In [163]:

import scipy.stats as ss
import scipy.optimize as so
In [164]:
#define a likelihood function
def likelihood_f(P, x, neg=1):
    n=np.round(P[0]) #by definition, it should be an integer 
    p=P[1]
    loc=np.round(P[2])
    return neg*(np.log(ss.nbinom.pmf(x, n, p, loc))).sum()
In [165]:
#generate a random variable
X=ss.nbinom.rvs(n=100, p=0.4, loc=0, size=1000)
In [166]:
#The likelihood
likelihood_f([100,0.4,0], X)
Out[166]:
-4400.3696690513316
In [167]:
#A simple fit, the fit is not good and the parameter estimate is way off
result=so.fmin(likelihood_f, [50, 1, 1], args=(X,-1), full_output=True, disp=False)
P1=result[0]
(result[1], result[0])
Out[167]:
(4418.599495886474, array([ 59.61196161,   0.28650831,   1.15141838]))
In [168]:
#Try a different set of start paramters, the fit is still not good and the parameter estimate is still way off
result=so.fmin(likelihood_f, [50, 0.5, 0], args=(X,-1), full_output=True, disp=False)
P1=result[0]
(result[1], result[0])
Out[168]:
(4417.1495981801972,
 array([  6.24809397e+01,   2.91877405e-01,   6.63343536e-04]))
In [169]:
#In this case we need a loop to get it right
result=[]
for i in range(40, 120): #in fact (80, 120) should probably be enough
    _=so.fmin(likelihood_f, [i, 0.5, 0], args=(X,-1), full_output=True, disp=False)
    result.append((_[1], _[0]))
In [170]:
#get the MLE
P2=sorted(result, key=lambda x: x[0])[0][1]
sorted(result, key=lambda x: x[0])[0]
Out[170]:
(4399.780263084549,
 array([  9.37289361e+01,   3.84587087e-01,   3.36856705e-04]))
In [171]:
#Which one is visually better?
plt.hist(X, bins=20, normed=True)
plt.plot(range(260), ss.nbinom.pmf(range(260), np.round(P1[0]), P1[1], np.round(P1[2])), 'g-')
plt.plot(range(260), ss.nbinom.pmf(range(260), np.round(P2[0]), P2[1], np.round(P2[2])), 'r-')
Out[171]:
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x109776c10>]
```

[image]

Comment: I realized it is a very ad-hoc solution. The optimization function does  not work always

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is quite old, but current readers may want to look at this repo which is made for this purpose: https://github.com/gokceneraslan/fit_nbinom

There's also an implementation here, though part of a larger package: https://github.com/ernstlab/ChromTime/blob/master/optimize.py

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this thread, and found an answer for anyone else wondering.

If you simply need the n, p parameterisation used by [scipy.stats.nbinom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nbinom.html) you can convert the mean and variance estimates:

```
mu = np.mean(sample)
sigma_sqr = np.var(sample)

n = mu**2 / (sigma_sqr - mu)
p = mu / sigma_sqr
```

If you the dispersionparameter you can use a negative binomial regression model from `statsmodels` with just an interaction term. This will find the dispersionparameter `alpha` using MLE.

```
# Data processing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Analysis models
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from scipy.stats import nbinom


def convert_params(mu, alpha):
    """
    Convert mean/dispersion parameterization of a negative binomial to the ones scipy supports

    Parameters
    ----------
    mu : float
       Mean of NB distribution.
    alpha : float
       Overdispersion parameter used for variance calculation.

    See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations
    """
    var = mu + alpha * mu ** 2
    p = mu / var
    r = mu ** 2 / (var - mu)
    return r, p


# Generate sample data
n = 2
p = 0.9
sample = nbinom.rvs(n=n, p=p, size=10000)


# Estimate parameters
## Mean estimates expectation parameter for negative binomial distribution
mu = np.mean(sample) 

## Dispersion parameter from nb model with only interaction term
nbfit = smf.negativebinomial("nbdata ~ 1", data=pd.DataFrame({"nbdata": sample})).fit()

alpha = nbfit.params[1]  # Dispersion parameter


# Convert parameters to n, p parameterization
n_est, p_est = convert_params(mu, alpha)


# Check that estimates are close to the true values:
print("""
                   {:<3}   {:<3}
True parameters:  {:<3}   {:<3}
Estimates      :  {:<3}   {:<3}""".format('n', 'p', n, p,
                                  np.round(n_est, 2), np.round(p_est, 2)))
```

Comment: It appears that in statsmodels>=0.14.0 the NegativeBinomial model includes method that returns a scipy.stats.nbinom distribution object  without any custom additional code https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.NegativeBinomial.get_distribution.html#statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.NegativeBinomial.get_distribution